# How do I reduce planetary photometry to standard viewing geometry using phase angle?

Tags: pluto, photometry

I'm trying to make light curves for Pluto using old data. Most papers give magnitudes "reduced to standard viewing geometry" of *r* = 39.5 AU, *Δ* = 38.5 AU, and *α* = 1 degree, where *r* is heliocentric distance, *Δ* is geocentric distance, and *α* is phase angle.

When papers give apparent magnitudes, I'm left to perform the reductions myself. I'm fine with the adjustment for *r* and *Δ*, but how do I reduce to phase angle of 1 degree?

I would also really appreciate a good source if you have it on hand.

Answer (score 1):

Phase functions are nonlinear in general, but Pluto presents such a small range of phases to Earth that a linear approximation will do:
about 0.03 mag/deg for Pluto and 0.08 mag/deg for Charon, or 0.04 mag/deg for the two together.
The [Stern and Tholen book](https://books.google.com/books?id=VcY7iYJwJZoC&pg=PA211&lpg=PA211&dq=Pluto+phase+coefficient&source=bl&ots=YDfEZAxWP3&sig=5nEneBnP92ozpOp2Ia-I1E3EFoo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiD4ZvMi9XNAhXCJB4KHURdCQIQ6AEITDAG#v=onepage&q=Pluto%20phase%20coefficient&f=false) summarizes the estimates up to 1997. 
A search for [Pluto phase coefficient](https://www.google.com/search?q=Pluto+phase+coefficient)
yields some of the papers behind those and more recent estimates.